# How to send HID commands over USB? Laird BT820 in HID-Proxy mode

Tags: bluetooth, proxy

I'm trying to get Bluetooth devices to work in HID-Proxy mode with a Laird BT820 dongle. According to their docs at http://cdn.lairdtech.com/home/brandworld/files/Application%20Note%20-%20BT800%20Series%20HID%20Proxy.pdf it states the following:

> Once a connection has taken place, the pairing is saved. The BT820 will always try to connect to same BLE device
> it has last connected to. The pairing entry needs to be cleared before it will connect to a new BLE device.
> The pairing can be removed with HID “SET_FEATURE_REQ” command over USB – “0x06 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
> 0x0”. For testing purposes, there is an exe file to remove the pairing.

I don't have the aforementioned exe file. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to send this SET_FEATURE_REQ command?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have been able to get the pairing to clear using this tool: https://github.com/chancefavorsthepreparedmind/csr_clear_pairings_cmd